# How to pass two value to controller method using ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, controller, return-value

I had two select box. First I select select box 1 value. Then i select select box 2 value. When I select select box 2 I try to pass value of select box 1 and 2 to controller method using ajax. I can pass only one value. How to pass two value.

Select box 1

```
            @foreach($routes as $route)
            <option name = 'origin' value='{{$route->rte_origin}}'>{{$route->rte_origin}}</option>
            @endforeach
```

Select box 2

```
{{ Form::select('destination', array(), null, array('class' => 'large', 'id'=>'destination')) }}
```

And my ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){    
  $('#destination').change(function(){
    var destination= $(this).find(':selected').text();

    $.get("{{ URL::route('getDate')}}", 
      {destination: destination},
      function(data) {
        var model = $('#ja');
        model.empty(); 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                  ................
            });
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select them separately (by id):

```
var origin = $(this).find('#origin').text();
var destination = $(this).find('#destination').text();
```

This is the data you are passing:

```
{destination: destination},
```

You can now change it to pass more items:

```
{origin: origin, destination: destination},
```

Comment: This is not a finished code, this is an idea of what you could do. For example, it will not work if you don't set the IDs in your HTML selects.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces around `{destination: destination}` mean it is an array, so you can add as many values as you would like seperated by commas. eg

```
{key1:value1, key2:value3, key3:value3}
```

Also you may be interested to know that the $.get function is just a shortcut for the full ajax function which gives much more functionality for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path/to.resource",
    type: "GET", //can be any HTTP VERB, eg GET,POST,PUT,DELETE etc...
    data:{data1:value1, data2:value2}, //any data you want to pass to the function
    async: true, //make call synchronous or asynchronous
    dataType:'json', //type of response you are expecting from server eg, text, json etc...
    success: function (data) {
        //code to run on successfully return. any returned data is contained in the data variable
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //code to run in the event of an error
    },
});
```

Full details on the use of the jquery ajax function can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/